# Displaying Checkmark in TableView by comparing multiple arrays in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode9

Stuck with this problem. Displaying name from below firstArray response in tableview. After displaying data calling another service secondArray. If secondArray id's matches with the firstArray id's display checkmark for the row. Checkmarks should be displayed to John and Robert in tableview.TIA

```
firstArray response :
(
 {
     Name = "Mike";
     id = 21;
 },
 {

     Name = "John";
     id = 91;
 },
 {

     Name = "Charles";
     id = 16;
 },
 {

     Name = "Robert";
     id = 18;
 }
 )


SecondArray Response :
(
 {
     Name = "John";
     id = 91;
 },
 {
     Name = "Robert";
     id = 18;
 }
 )
```

No idea how to do this. Below is what i have tried

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    }
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [firstArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You have nthg tried related to your issue. your code just used to show the data which is the first array. Where is the code for comparison??

Comment: `NSSet *secondIDs = [NSSet setWithArray:[secondArray valueForKeyPath:@"id"]]; if ([secondIDs containsObject:dict[@"id"]]){//Apply Checkmark}else{//Remove Checkmark}`. BUT I'd strongly suggest to use custom object instead of Dictionary, and use a property to define if it's inside the the second or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    }
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [firstArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];

    // here set none accessory to prevent showing in dequeue

    for NSDictionary*dd in otherArray
    {
         if([[dict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualTo:[dd objectForKey:@"id"]])
         {
             // set access

             break;
          }
    }
    return cell;

}
```